# In linux, is it possible to do partial reads on a regular file

Tags: c, linux

I need to write an application that spits out log entries to a regular file at a very fast rate. Also, there will be another process, that can read the same file concurrently at the time, other process would be writing to it. 
I have following questions

1. How does read() determine EOF, specially in the case, where the underlying file could be concurrently being modified?
2. Is it possible for read() to return partially written data from the other process write? For example, the write process wrote half a line and read would pick that half line and return?

The application would be written in C on linux 2.6.x using Ex4 filesystem

UPDATE:
Below link points to the patch, that locks inode in EXT4, before reading and writing. 
http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/91834/

Comment: I think that's famous reader's writer's problem , and better to implement it using `lock` or `semaphore`

Comment: Look at this: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c

Comment: ad 2) No. in unix, read & write are atomic (to at least the blocklevel). For actions larger than 1 block, I don't know if the filesystem guarantees the order of operations.

Comment: @wildplasser Can you point me to some documentation which says writes upto one block level are atomic?

Comment: @wildplasser There is no such guarantee but it works 99% of the time, since `write()` syscall locks the inode it is about to write into, hence serializing all writers. In 1% of the time it will be a partial `write()`.

Comment: Eh, Stevens? Bach ? The online manual. BTWL: you were talking about "lines". For read() and write(), lines don't exist. And a (logical) line could span more than one physical block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does read() determine EOF, specially in the case, where the underlying file could be concurrently being modified?

When you try to `read()` past the end of the file it returns `EOF`. You can still seek the file back and forward and read again (only if the file descriptor refers to a file, not a pipe or socket though).

> Is it possible for read() to return partially written data from the other process write? For example, the write process wrote half a line and read would pick that half line and return?

Quite possible.

Comment: Isnt write in linux atomic?

Comment: @Jimm Regardless of whether writes are block-atomic, what happens when a single line spans a block boundary?

Comment: @twalberg i never said block atomic. Simply atomic. Infact, can you please point me towards the source of writes being block atomic in linux?

Comment: @Jimm writes are not atomic, generally. There is a special atomicity requirement for pipes, but not for everything else.

Comment: If I call `write()` with a 64KB buffer, I'm fairly certain the actual write can be broken up into smaller pieces, so it's not fully atomic. However, others have suggested that it's atomic to the single block level (I'm not entirely convinced that that's always true, either).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/43427/focus=43445 shows discussion by linus, stating writes in linux are atomic, block or gigabytes.

Comment: @Jimm that post is 10 years old. As I mentioned, single `write()` syscall is atomic 99% of the time.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin what use cases fall under 1% failure?

Comment: @Jimm When there are too many dirty pages in the page cache it depends on the filesystem whether it returns a partial write immediately, or blocks till the entire `write()` has completed.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Also, the write can be interrupted by a signal causing a partial buffer write. If this happens the read can pick up that partial write, *even if writes are atomic*. OK, possibly this only applies to other Unixes and not to Linux and files. But it does happen on Linux when writing to a terminal, for sure, because I have seen it and filed bugs on glibc about it.